# Single query to get subset of facts from PuppetDB API

Tags: api, rest, puppet

I'm looking to send a single query to the PuppetDB REST API to return to me a subset of a node's stored facts.

So if the `mynode.example.com` node has 200 facts, and I want (for example) the `macaddress` and `puppetversion` facts, could you please provide an example curl query to get only those two?

I have tried a few variations on the `extract` query parameter, but I can't seem to find the magic spot that returns data (I either get parse errors or empty results).

Comment: Can you add a query that you tried, as a starting point for people who might be able to help?